# Error converting data type varchar to bigint. when using update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server. I'm trying to run the following SQL script and I'm getting this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

This is the script:

```
with T as
(
    select 
        sp.ProfileId
       ,sp.ProfileHandle
       ,sp.[Description]
    from 
        [SocialProfile] sp 
    inner join 
        Entity e on sp.EntityId = e.EntityId
    where 
        e.EntityStatusId != 3 and e.EntityStatusId != 4 
        and sp.SocialProfileTypeId in (1, 2, 10) 
        and (ISNUMERIC(sp.ProfileHandle) = 1)
        and IsRemoved = 0
)
update T 
set ProfileHandle = NULL
where ProfileHandle = ProfileId
```

I tried to use cast function but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably ProfileId is varchar type.. Use convert function

Comment: What is the value that is causing the error? Remember that `ISNUMERIC('123.45,6')` and `ISNUMERIC('123,4.56')` is true!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isnumeric()` doesn't give the protection you want.  Use `try_convert()` for the comparison:

```
with T as (
      select sp.ProfileId, sp.ProfileHandle, sp.[Description]
      from [SocialProfile] sp inner join 
           Entity e
           on sp.EntityId = e.EntityId
       where e.EntityStatusId not in (3, 4) and
             sp.SocialProfileTypeId in (1, 2, 10) and
             ISNUMERIC(sp.ProfileHandle) = 1 and  -- you can leave it in
             IsRemoved = 0
    )
update T 
    set ProfileHandle = NULL
where try_convert(int, ProfileHandle) = ProfileId;
```

SQL Server has a "feature" where it will rearrange the conditions in the query.  The CTE does not get executed "first", so the `isnumeric()` is not necessarily run before the conversion in the `where`.  I consider this a bug.  Microsoft considers this a feature (because it provides more options for optimization).

The only ordering guaranteed in a query is through `case` expressions.  The simplest work-around is `try_convert()`.

In addition, I strongly recommend never relying on implicit conversions.  Always explicitly convert.  I have spent many hours debugging code for problems caused by implicit conversion.